# Replace string with a slash character with sed

Tags: sed

I have a directory's tree with several files inside.
I want to replace in every file, the string `index.html` for a character `/`.
Since `/` is a special character, How can I instruct to the linux "sed" command so I can change all files that I have under a directory?

Thanks!

Comment: The first character of the pattern determines the separator; there is nothing special about /, it's just often seen as the separator. I like to use @ if I need to use / in a pattern. e.g. echo 'a/index.html' | sed 's@index.html@/@g' gives a//

Comment: Alternatively, although maybe not as readable as Nick's suggestion, one can, in typical Unix fashion, escape the `/` with a `\`: `sed 's/index.html/\//g'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sed is usualy used with `/` as a separator. Actually you can use any symbol as a separator, sed just uses the first symbol after `s` command for that. For example `sed 's|/|slash|'`. Or you can escape `/` like that `sed s/\//slash/`. It's dangerous command, be careful, make a backup of your dir:

```
for file in `find /your/dir/ -type f`; do sed -i "$file" 's|index.html|/|g'; done
```

Comment: Boo, hiss. [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- this will fail badly if names contain spaces or can be interpreted as glob characters. See also [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Much safer (and somewhat more efficient) to write `find /your/dir/ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's|index.html|/|g' {} +`